is it possible to merge two autohotkey script?
Is it possible to join these 2 script?
This to use my remote control RC Modelism and the helmet VR oculus quest 2
I would like to use that the H and B keys on the VR Oculus Quest helmet and on the transmitter control RC the space key, the rest can delete it
keyboard H = X key oculus quest,
keyboard B = Y key oculus quest,
keyboard Space = RC transmitter,

script for Oculus quest 2:
#include auto_oculus_touch.ahk
; vJoy Example
; Set up Touch controllers as a gamepad using vJoy.

; Start the Oculus sdk.
InitOculus()

; Main polling loop.
Loop {
    ; Grab the latest Oculus input state (Touch, Remote and Xbox One).
    Poll()

    ; Move the mouse using the right thumb stick.
    rightX:= GetAxis(AxisXRight)
    rightY:= GetAxis(AxisYRight)
    if (rightX>0.1) or (rightX<-0.1) or (rightY>0.1) or (rightY<-0.1)
        SendRawMouseMove(rightX*20,rightY*-20,0)

    ; Use the A button as a left mouse button
    if IsPressed(ovrA)
        SendRawMouseButtonDown(LeftMouse)
    if IsReleased(ovrA)
        SendRawMouseButtonUp(LeftMouse)

    ; Use Right touch stick as right mouse
    if IsTouchDown(ovrTouch_RThumb)
        SendRawMouseButtonDown(RightMouse)
    if IsTouchReleased(ovrTouch_RThumb)
        SendRawMouseButtonup(RightMouse)
  
    ; Use the left thumbstick as zoom
    leftX:= GetAxis(AxisXLeft)
    leftY:= GetAxis(AxisYLeft)
    if (leftY>0.1)
        Send {WheelUp}, Sleep 50
        ;SendRawMouseMove(0,0,1), Sleep 75
    if (leftY<-0.1)
        Send {WheelDown}, Sleep 50
        ;SendRawMouseMove(0,0,-1), Sleep 75

    ; Use Y as Character View
     if IsPressed(ovrY)
        SendInput {b Down}
    if IsReleased(ovrY)
        SendInput {b Up} 

    ; Use X as Eye View
     if IsPressed(ovrX)
        SendInput {h down}
    if IsReleased(ovrX)
        SendInput {h up} 

    ; Use Left Menu button as free cam
    if IsPressed(ovrEnter)
        SendInput {v down}
    if IsReleased(ovrEnter)
        SendInput {v up}

    ; Use Left Index Trigger E
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerLeft, 0.8) == 1
        SendInput {e down}
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerLeft, 0.8) == -1
        SendInput {e up}

    ; Use Left Hand Trigger as Q
    if Reached(AxisHandTriggerLeft, 0.8) == 1
        SendInput {Q down}
    if Reached(AxisHandTriggerLeft, 0.8) == -1
        SendInput {Q up}

    ; Use Right Index Trigger E
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerRight, 0.8) == 1
        SendInput {Ctrl down}
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerRight, 0.8) == -1
        SendInput {Ctrl up}   
    Sleep, 10
}

script for RC transmitter:
#Persistent  ; Keep this script running until the user explicitly exits it.
SetTimer, WatchAxis, 5
return

WatchAxis:

JoyR := GetKeyState("JoyR")  ; Get position of X axis
KeyToHoldDownPrev := KeyToHoldDown  ; Prev now holds the key that was down before (if any).

if (JoyR > 30)
    KeyToHoldDown := "Space Down"
else if (JoyR < 80)
    KeyToHoldDown := "Space Up"
else    
    KeyToHoldDown := ""

if (KeyToHoldDown = KeyToHoldDownPrev)  ; The correct key is already down (or no key is needed).
    return  ; Do nothing.

; Otherwise, release the previous key and press down the new key:
SetKeyDelay -1  ; Avoid delays between keystrokes.
if KeyToHoldDownPrev   ; There is a previous key to release.
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDownPrev% up}  ; Release it.
if KeyToHoldDown   ; There is a key to press down.
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDown% down}  ; Press it down.
return


Give this a try...
** UNTESTED **
#include auto_oculus_touch.ahk 
 
InitOculus() 
 
Loop { 
    Poll() 
 
    rightX:= GetAxis(AxisXRight) 
    rightY:= GetAxis(AxisYRight) 
    if (rightX>0.1) or (rightX<-0.1) or (rightY>0.1) or (rightY<-0.1) 
        SendRawMouseMove(rightX*20,rightY*-20,0) 
 
    if IsPressed(ovrA) 
        SendRawMouseButtonDown(LeftMouse) 
    if IsReleased(ovrA) 
        SendRawMouseButtonUp(LeftMouse) 
 
    if IsTouchDown(ovrTouch_RThumb) 
        SendRawMouseButtonDown(RightMouse) 
    if IsTouchReleased(ovrTouch_RThumb) 
        SendRawMouseButtonUp(RightMouse) 
 
    leftX:= GetAxis(AxisXLeft) 
    leftY:= GetAxis(AxisYLeft) 
    if (leftY>0.1) 
        Send {WheelUp} 
    if (leftY<-0.1) 
        Send {WheelDown} 
 
    if IsPressed(ovrY) 
        SendInput {b Down} 
    if IsReleased(ovrY) 
        SendInput {b Up} 
 
    if IsPressed(ovrX) 
        SendInput {h down} 
    if IsReleased(ovrX) 
        SendInput {h up} 
 
    if IsPressed(ovrEnter) 
        SendInput {v down} 
    if IsReleased(ovrEnter) 
        SendInput {v up} 
 
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerLeft, 0.8) == 1 
        SendInput {e down} 
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerLeft, 0.8) == -1 
        SendInput {e up} 
 
    if Reached(AxisHandTriggerLeft, 0.8) == 1 
        SendInput {Q down} 
    if Reached(AxisHandTriggerLeft, 0.8) == -1 
        SendInput {Q up} 
 
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerRight, 0.8) == 1 
        SendInput {Ctrl down} 
    if Reached(AxisIndexTriggerRight, 0.8) == -1 
        SendInput {Ctrl up} 
   
    Sleep, 10 
} 
 
#Persistent 
SetTimer, WatchAxis, 5 
Return 
 
WatchAxis: 
JoyR := GetKeyState("JoyR") 
KeyToHoldDownPrev := KeyToHoldDown 
 
if (JoyR > 30) 
    KeyToHoldDown := "Space Down" 
else if (JoyR < 80) 
    KeyToHoldDown := "Space Up" 
else 
    KeyToHoldDown := "" 
 
if (KeyToHoldDown = KeyToHoldDownPrev) 
    Return 
 
SetKeyDelay -1 
if KeyToHoldDownPrev 
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDownPrev% up} 
if KeyToHoldDown 
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDown% down} 
Return 


It does not work, I already tested by sticking the 2 scripts one below the other, damage , thank you as the same
